# Java апплет - сторонняя библиотека не может найти другой сторонний класс

Tags: java, исключения, applet

Я разрабатываю JAVA апплет для электронной подписи документов, на серверной стороне находится код

```
  echo "<Applet Code=\"Main.class\" 
        name = \"eParakstitajs\"
        mayscript=\"true\"
        codebase = \"".SERVER_FULL_URL."/EDOC2.4.0._22.05\"
        archive = \"
        classesEDOC2.4.jar,
        log4j-1.2.17.jar,
        eparaksts-bc-1.43.0.jar, 
        eparaksts-client-2.4.0.jar, 
        eparaksts-lib-2.4.0.jar, 
        org.apache.commons.codec_1.3.0.v201101211617.jar, 
        pkcs11wrapper-1.2.18.jar,
        plugin.jar, 
        signing-applet-2.4.0.jar, 
        slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar, 
        slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar, 

        xmlsec-2.0.2.jar, 

        ./config/\"  
        width=1 
        Height=1
          >
    <PARAM NAME=\"key\"         VALUE=\"{$signKey}\">
    <PARAM NAME=\"URL\"         VALUE=\"".SERVER_FULL_URL."\">
    <PARAM NAME=\"PIN1\"        VALUE=\"{$_SESSION["userdata"]["PIN1"]}\">
    <PARAM NAME=\"PIN2\"        VALUE=\"{$_SESSION["userdata"]["PIN2"]}\">
    <PARAM NAME=\"USERID\"      VALUE=\"{$user[0]["id_lietotajs"]}\">
</Applet>";
```

На этом этапе всё в порядке, архив classesEDOC2.4.jar это мои классы, а всё остальное это уже скомпилированные сторонние библиотеки.
По необходимости в моём классе нужно создать объект класса QualifiedSignatureHelper, которые находится в архиве eparaksts-lib-2.4.0.jar, но во время объявления появляется исключение -

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at lv.eparaksts.helpers.QualifiedSignatureHelper.<clinit>(QualifiedSignatureHelper.java:26)
    at CreateNewSignTimestampedAction.CreateNewSignTimestamped(CreateNewSignTimestampedAction.java:128)

    at Main.init(Main.java:221)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.init(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

Исходя из ошибки, класс QualifiedSignatureHelper не может найти org.apache.log4j, декомпилировав QualifiedSignatureHelper там обнаружил строчку

```
  private static final Logger I = Logger.getLogger(QualifiedSignatureHelper.class);
```

И что самое удивительное, выше находится соответствующий импорт -

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

В чём тогда может быть причина ошибки?

Comment: Вы уверены, что на серверной стороне ваши библиотеки все выложены? Очевидно же, что во время компиляции либы есть, а во время выполнения их нет в `CLASSPATH`, который указан в `ARCHIVE`

Comment: @Barmaley В то то и заключается парадоксальность ситуации, что все .JARы совпадают с тем что перечисленно в параметре Archive

Comment: И они лежат в каталоге: `SERVER_FULL_URL/EDOC2.4.0._22.05`?

Comment: Именно так, 
Товарищи с англоязычного StackOverflow высказали предположение что это как то связано с несовместимостью библиотек.