# Добавить classpath из другого jar архива

Tags: java, исключения, applet

Сразу извиняюсь за то что вопрос сформулировано скорее всего неправильно, но на текущий момент я весьма плохо разбираюсь в особенностях разработки Java апплетов, и решением возникающих проблем.
Корни проблемы исходят 
[вот из этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426953/java-%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81)

ситуация, следующая: на стороне сервера где объявлен апплет, находятся библиотеки

```
classesEDOC2.4.jar,
    log4j-1.2.17.jar,
    eparaksts-bc-1.43.0.jar, 
    eparaksts-client-2.4.0.jar, 
    eparaksts-lib-2.4.0.jar, 
    org.apache.commons.codec_1.3.0.v201101211617.jar, 
    pkcs11wrapper-1.2.18.jar,
    plugin.jar, 
    signing-applet-2.4.0.jar, 
    slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar, 
    slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar,
```

Разумеется все перечисленные библиотеки находятся в нужном каталоге и на этом этапе всё в порядке. ClassesEDOC2.4 (В нём же находится класс Main.class, который начинает работу апплета) это архив с моими классами для работы Апплета, все остальные являются third-party. Как было сказано предыдущем вопросе, класс QualifiedSignatureHelper который находится в пакете eparaksts-lib-2.4.0.jar не может найти класс Logger.class который в свою очередь находится в log4j-1.2.17.jar. И вопрос заключается в следующем, можно ли с помощью командной строки, добавить в архив eparaksts-lib-2.4.0.jar classpath из, например log4j-1.2.17.jar, или подскажите пожалуйста лучшее решение моей проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте посмотреть в http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-classpath-windows/

Абзац "*Настройка classpath*".

> В больших проектах повторная компиляция каждого файла может быть достаточно затратной с точки зрения времени. Вы можете облегчить нагрузку путем раздельного компилирования и хранения отдельных частей одного и того же проекта в различных директориях bin. Данные директории добавляются в classpath.
>
> Существует несколько способов добавления класса в classpath. Однако следует использовать только переключатель командной строки -classpath. Например, предположим, что я хочу импортировать файлы из другого проекта, которые я предварительно скомпилировал в директории C:\lib\classes. Тогда я добавлю -classpath C:\lib\classes в командную строку следующим образом:

```
C:\project> javac -d bin -sourcepath src -classpath C:\lib\classes
  src\com\elharo\gui\MainFrame.java
```

> Теперь предположим, что мне необходимо добавить две директории, C:\project1\classes и C:\project2\classes. Тогда укажем их, разделив точкой с запятой следующим образом:

```
C:\project> javac -d bin -sourcepath src
  -classpath C:\project1\classes;C:\project2\classes
  src\com\elharo\gui\MainFrame.java
```